# Putting the value of a text field into another string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

When I write this:

```
NSLog("Text Value %@",statutsField.text);
```

It work fine , but when I do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyUrl/%@",statutsField.text];
```

I get an error:

> too many argument to method call, expected ...

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URLWithString:` only accepts one argument; one single `NSString`. You are passing it two, the string `@"http://MyUrl/%@"` and the string in `statutsField.text`.

You need to construct a combined version of the string, and pass that combined version to `URLWithString:`. Use [`+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_) for this:

```
NSString * myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyUrl/%@", statutsField.text]
NSURL * myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];
```

The function `NSLog` accepts a *variable* number of arguments, based on the number of [format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) that it finds in its first string (the format string); this is why your `NSLog` call works. The method `stringWithFormat:` works similarly. For each `%@` it finds in its first argument, it takes an object from the rest of the argument list and puts it into the resulting string.

For details, you can see [Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) in the String Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyUrl/%@",statutsField.text]];`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *base = @"http://MyUrl/";
NSString *urlString = [base stringByAppendingString:statutsField.text];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

The method `URLWithString` accepts only 1 argument, but you are passing 2 arguments, ie, the string `@"http://MyUrl/%@"` and `statutsField.text`

So you have to concatenate the string beforehand, or use the `stringWithFormat` method of `NSString` inline.